# .git/tags file is HUGE

Tags: git, tags, npm

**Question**
What reason would make a .git/tags file 27gb?
When do I need this file?
How can I shrink it or avoid it completely?

**Problem**
My laptop is crashing from my 500gb HD filling up.

**Investigation**
After inspection it turns out that my .git/tags files in multiple repos are HUGE. 27gb on average.

**Workflow**

1. I work in a branch

   Push my changes to github

   Make a pull request

   Pull to master locally once the pull request lands

   I use npm version to make a tag and increment the version number in package.json in one step

   npm publish

Any suggestions?

Comment: Figured it out, and **YES** I was doing something **really dumb**.

I had added git hooks from this blog post:
http://tbaggery.com/2011/08/08/effortless-ctags-with-git.html

They never worked so I forgot I had added them. Deleting my  ~/.git_template directory solved the problem.

Let this be a lesson to me.

Comment: related: https://github.com/yongkangchen/atom-ctags/issues/157 this is about the `.tags` file, that is not located inside the `.git` folder, and it is used for a better auto-completion in many editors

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've been t-bagged!!!

http://tbaggery.com/2011/08/08/effortless-ctags-with-git.html

Comment: yould you explain a bit, what went wrong and what is the conclusion of that solution?

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring media assets would do that. Drop the git change history (by reseting the project for example w/ initial checkin)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some different configuration in your git that makes tags a file?

Inside of your git repository, there should be a directory that you can find at .git/refs/tags should be a directory, and it should contain one file for each git tag that you create.

Each git tag is only one file containing a commit hash.  It would be extremely hard for that directory to be 27 GB.  Are you sure that the tags directory is 27 GB?  Could it be another directory?

Do you have a lot of binary files, such as images or videos that you are storing in your git repository?

Comment: This is a different file. I do have .git/refs/tags as well. There are no binary files.

Answer (score 0):

You probably opened the complete `.git` folder in an editor like `atom` and did a **project wide search**, which will create a `.tags` file inside the current directory for auto-completion which can get really huge, if you are inside a .git folder